# nginx config to create subdomain from domain proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a domain and subdomain for my domain name in nginx server for  `www.example.com/users`  to `www.people.example.com`
i am able to configure subdomain but when i typed url in browser of subdomain url  it is redirecting to `www.example.com/users`
But i need it to be in subdomain

is there anything that i missed in nginx config? please provide me any suggestion nginx config for subdomain

```
server
{
server_name people.example.com www.people.example.com;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
location / {
proxy_pass http://example.com/users$request_uri;

proxy_set_header "Host" $host;
proxy_redirect http://$host/users http://$host;
}
```

And also suggest me config for `www.example.com` to block access via `www.example.com/users` but can be accessed via `www.people.example.com`

Comment: And also i want to block direct access of url "www.example.com/users" where it has to be accessed via www.people.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting from a separate server stanza. Then remove the `proxy_*` commands from the `people.example.com` server.

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location = /users {
        return 301 http://people.exxmple.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I tried it but same result and i am going to use "http://people.example.com" for http call  externally which is going to use url "http://example.com/users"